# OAuth implementation in SOAP API (C#)

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, oauth2, c#, oauth

I would like help how I can append Soap Header with following header in C#. Currently we are passing user credentials in the header. I need a help how we can replace with FuelOauth node in C#? As per [Using Fuel oAuth with the SOAP API](http://www.kellyjandrews.com/2014/02/20/using-fuel-oauth-with-the-soap-api.html)

[image]

```
<Header>
    <fueloauth xmlns="http://exacttarget.com">YOURACCESSTOKEN</fueloauth>
</Header>
```

---

```
_etSoapApiClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName =  ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["wsUserName"];

_etSoapApiClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["wsPassword"];

  var clientID = new ClientID { ID = XXXXXXX, IDSpecified = true }; 


        var definition = new TriggeredSendDefinition { CustomerKey = "TEST", Client = clientID };


        var triggeredSend = new TriggeredSend
        {
            TriggeredSendDefinition = definition,
            Client = clientID,
            Subscribers = CreateSubscribers()
        };



        APIObject[] apiObject = { triggeredSend };
        String requestId;
        String overAllStatus;
        var createOptionsAsynchronous = new CreateOptions { RequestType = RequestType.Asynchronous, RequestTypeSpecified = true };

        var createOptionsSynchronous = new CreateOptions { RequestType = RequestType.Synchronous, RequestTypeSpecified = true };

           var createResults = _etSoapApiClient.Create(createOptionsAsynchronous, apiObject, out requestId, out overAllStatus);

        var tsCreateResults = createResults[0] as TriggeredSendCreateResult;

        SubscriberResult[]  subscriberResult = tsCreateResults.SubscriberFailures;
```

Thanks Daniel.

I am getting below exception

```
System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled
```

HResult=-2146233079
  **Message=The username is not provided. Specify username in ClientCredentials.**
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
    Server stack trace: 
       at System.ServiceModel.ClientCredentialsSecurityTokenManager.CreateSecurityTokenProvider(SecurityTokenRequirement tokenRequirement, Boolean disableInfoCard)
       at System.ServiceModel.ClientCredentialsSecurityTokenManager.CreateSecurityTokenProvider(SecurityTokenRequirement tokenRequirement)
       at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityProtocol.AddSupportingTokenProviders(SupportingTokenParameters supportingTokenParameters, Boolean isOptional, IList`1 providerSpecList)
       at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityProtocol.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Security.WrapperSecurityCommunicationObject.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityProtocol.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelFactory`1.ClientSecurityChannel`1.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOpenOnce.System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ICallOnce.Call(ServiceChannel channel, TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOnceManager.CallOnce(TimeSpan timeout, CallOnceManager cascade)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EnsureOpened(TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
    Exception rethrown at [0]: 
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
       at

and below is my WCF end point

```
<bindings>
  <customBinding>
    <binding name="SoapBinding" closeTimeout="00:40:00" openTimeout="00:40:00" receiveTimeout="00:40:00" sendTimeout="00:40:00">
      <security authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport">
        <secureConversationBootstrap />
      </security>
      <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11WSAddressingAugust2004" />
      <httpsTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="655360000" />
    </binding>
  </customBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="https://webservice.exacttarget.com/Service.asmx" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="SoapBinding" contract="ExactTargetClient.Soap" name="Soap" />
</client>
```

Comment: Are you using WCF to interact with the Marketing Cloud SOAP API?

Comment: I am consuming SOAP API from .NET application.

Comment: I am implemented the changes. But I see the exception.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recently had some challenges adding a SOAP Header when creating a Universal Windows Platform (UWP) application in .NET against the SOAP based APIs.

The problem was that the WCF tooling for importing WSDLs in UWP apps doesn't automatically generate the SOAP Header classes. You need to create your own header by implementing `System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageHeader` and a corresponding `IClientMessageInspector`.

There are some well written notes on how to implement this in [Calling Salesforce SOAP APIs from a .NET Core or UWP App](http://www.ideliverable.com/blog/calling-salesforce-soap-apis-from-a-net-core-or-uwp-app)

For reference, there is the [Marketing Cloud API - Connecting to the SOAP API using WCF](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/connecting_to_the_web_service_api_using_wcf.htm), but it doesn't seem to reference FuelOauth in the linked WSDLs.

---

```
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;
using System.Xml;

namespace XYZ.ForceClient.Core
{
    internal class FuelOAuthHeader : MessageHeader
    {
        public FuelOAuthHeader(string accessToken)
        {
            _accessToken = accessToken;
        }

        private string _accessToken;

        public override string Name => "fueloauth";

        public override string Namespace => "http://exacttarget.com";

        protected override void OnWriteHeaderContents(XmlDictionaryWriter writer, MessageVersion messageVersion)
        {
            writer.WriteElementString("fueloauth", _accessToken);
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
using System;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;
using System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher;

namespace XYZ.ForceClient.Core
{
    internal class FuelOAuthInspector : IClientMessageInspector
    {
        public FuelOAuthInspector(string accessToken)
        {
            _accessToken = accessToken;
        }

        private string _accessToken;

        public void AfterReceiveReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
        {

        }

        public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
        {
            request.Headers.Add(new FuelOAuthHeader(_accessToken));

            return Guid.NewGuid();
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;
using System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher;

namespace XYZ.ForceClient.Core
{
    internal class FuelOAuthHeaderBehavior : IEndpointBehavior
    {
        public FuelOAuthHeaderBehavior(string accessToken)
        {
            _accessToken = accessToken;
        }

        private string _accessToken;

        public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
        {

        }

        public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
        {
            clientRuntime.ClientMessageInspectors.Add(new FuelOAuthInspector(_accessToken));
        }

        public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher)
        {

        }

        public void Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

---

Then whey you need to use the header do something like:

```
_etSoapApiClient.Endpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add(
    new FuelOAuthHeaderBehavior(fuelOAuthAccessToken)
);
```

Comment: Thanks. I am looking into this exactly  "For reference, there is the Marketing Cloud API - Connecting to the SOAP API using WCF, but it doesn't seem to reference FuelOauth in the linked WSDLs."  But I found below link and but I am not sure how to consume.  http://www.kellyjandrews.com/2014/02/20/using-fuel-oauth-with-the-soap-api.html

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I implemented same. But I am getting below exception

Comment: @Reddy You might need to verify the approach before trying it in C#. I find Soap UI to be really useful for experimenting with APIs.

Comment: Thanks again Danial. This works now. We are consuming SOAP API in .NET core and implemented above functionality. I am able to see the response.